# What is solicited network traffic and what is unsolicited network traffic?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, firewall, rras

I've recently read [a Microsoft Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727017%28printer%29.aspx) on how Windows Firewall works. The author of the article uses concepts like 'solicited network traffic' and 'unsolicited network traffic' for a machine. I guess I don't fully understand the concept of those.

In relation to TCP protocol, is the solicited traffic a traffic that was initiated by a local machine?

In relation to UDP protocol, is there even sth like a solicited/unsolicited traffic or is all traffic unsolicited?

What about other protocols? (+can Windows Firewall filter those other protocols)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, solicited traffic is traffic that was initiated by you.  Solicited traffic automatically gets a pass, no matter the port, because you initiated it.  This alleviates a lot of the headaches of traditional firewalls, e.g., having to open up ALL the ephemeral ports, because Windows Firewall will keep track of the session state for you.

Comment: Strange, I could swear that this was Evan Anderson's answer. My eyes must be failing me.

Comment: Does 'initiated by me' reference only to the TCP based connection?

Comment: Even though UDP doesn't really have the concept of a "connection," most firewalls record the socket pair (source IP + port, destination IP + port) and will allow replies that fit this pattern until a timeout passes without traffic, tearing down the "connection". There is also a similar mechanism known as stateful packet inspection.